# Google tag manager - Get GA4 event value from another tag manager event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I need to configure GA4 ecommerce event for a full integration inside conversion tab in the new Google Analitycs version. I have a tag manager configured with some custom variables to get dataLayer from checkout process and other things. I need to get this DataLayer value to use it in GA4 event.

My current event is called 'InitiateCheckout' and has this DataLayer:

```
{
  event: 'InitiateCheckout',
  gtm: {
    uniqueEventId: 13,
    start: 1615035423900,
    scrollThreshold: 90,
    scrollUnits: 'percent',
    scrollDirection: 'vertical',
    triggers: '1_33'
  },
  gtag: {targets: {AW-412426139: {}}},
  content_name: 'Product 123A',
  value: '9.99',
  currency: 'EUR'
}
```

I need to extract 'content_name', 'value' and 'currency' to compile 'begin_checkout" GA4 events as mentioned in the [official guide](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9268036?hl=en&ref_topic=9756175). When i start my configuration i can't figure a way out to insert this data as a value of the event parameter. How can i call it?

Unfortunately I can't change the name of the events I'm already recording to match the GA4 events features, the platform doesn't allow this so I need to find a way to get this value from another event.

[GA4 event parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3gmI.png)
[Tag Manager current Event DataLayer preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNfYs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple push to the dataLayer of some values. I don't know how they are used in your system but with the information I see just need to create a **Data Layer Variable** that has the **name** of the parameter of interest as its name (i.e. Data Layer Value called `DL content_name` and variabile name equals to `content_name`), then enter the value of your variable in the value field of your GA4 tag, i.e. `{{DL content_name}}`.

### EDIT

You can create a custom event trigger named `InitiateCheckout` and associate it with the GA4 tag, so you can access those values ​​by creating dataLayer variables and use them in the tag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I can't push the variables in this way.
My data layer information are inside a custom event (linked to my platform, I cant edit it - [here some info](https://help.uscreen.tv/en/articles/4316237-google-tag-manager-integration)) so I can't split or get that value individually.
When generated this DataLayer value are inside this custom event.
I need to get this value from this event. Are there some command to get this value from another dataLayer event? Something as InitiateCheckout.content_name.

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly the situation, I assume that the dataLayer is shared and you can create trigger in your GTM. Anyway I edited my answer.